# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getcwd'

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I'm trying to unzip a file in my current script directory but I can't get this work...

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.getcwd() + '/Sample_APE_File.zip')
zip.extractall(os.getcwd())
```

Error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getcwd'`

Comment: You should be doing somthing like `os = "a string"` before in your code

Comment: Aside: `zip` is the name of a very useful python [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip).  If you use it as the name for one of your own variables, then you'll have similar problems due to shadowing if you try to use the built-in `zip` later..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned a string value to `os`, it is no longer bound to the module:

```
os = 'some string'
```

Rename that to something else.

Comment: Yes! I'm so stupid xD `from sys import platform as _platform
if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
  
 os = "Linux"
elif _platform == "darwin":`